# Is there a VBA code that check and moves values from A column to the beginning of B column?

Tags: excel

I found a lot of formulas on the Internet which copies "n characters" but they did not provide a solution for me. I am searching for a VBA code which is able to move the specific value from a column to the beginning of adjacent column. For example, the VBA code will  check the A column for the word "Warm" and "Cold", and if they are available, it will move them as shown in the example. Thank you in advance for your help.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdj5t.png)

**Edit ( Solution by @Dominique ):** `=IF(A1<>"";IF(RIGHT(A1;4)="Warm";"Warm "&B1;B1))`

Comment: Have you tried using `InStr` for example?

Comment: @BigBen I am so sorry that I did not mention that I am not knowledgeable about VBA codes. When I try to do something or hit on idea in Excel, I search it on Google and try the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't move a part of one cell to another. This is what you need to do:

- Search for " Warm" (or " Cold") in a cell in column A and replace " Warm" (or " Cold") by an empty string within that cell.
- Take the cell, next to that (use the `Offset()` function) and add the word "Warm " (or "Cold ") at the beginning of that cell.
- Do this for the entire A column.

Comment: I found a formula and adjusted it with "Warm" word. **=IF(A1<>"";IF(RIGHT(A1;4)="Warm";B1&"Warm"))**
But this formula adds the word to the most right of the sentence and I cannot make it for the most left even though I tried much. Also, copying or adding will be fine for me instead of moving. I can deal with A column later.

Comment: @NewbieforAye: just replace `B1&"Warm"` by `"Warm "&B1`, that will put it at the left side.

Comment: @NewbieforAye: Is this what you need? ____________________
`=IF(A1<>"";IF(RIGHT(A1;4)="Warm";"Warm "&B1))`

Comment: I have been trying to make it since I saw your comment 1 hour ago. It worked for putting it on the left but it gives FALSE value for the cells that does not have "Warm" word. I could not figure out how to copy cells that does not have "Warm" as they are.

Comment: @NewbieforAye: the `IF()`-function has an `ELSE`-clause, which is the last parameter. In order to fill it in, you do the following: __________________`=IF(A1<>"";IF(RIGHT(A1;4)="Warm";"Warm "&B1;B1))`

Comment: This one made it. Then I will copy the B column and paste as value and will run the formula for "Cold" word. Thank you so much for your interest and help.